# How to prevent trimming whitespaces in JSP page

Tags: jstl

Example

```
String var="welcome     to JSP";
<c:out value=${test}"/>
```

the above standard tag library trimming the spaces from string var , also tried to display same var on JSP without JSTL still the whitespaces have been takenout.

Comment: You should include some code here, this is not enough information to determine the cause of the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

The JSTL doesn't trim white spaces at all. Look at the generated HTML by right-clicking in the page and choosing "view page source", and you'll see that the white spaces are there.

HTML does that. One white space or 100 successive ones are rendered the same way in HTML (as a single white space), unless you use a CSS style that makes them relevant, like for example

```
<pre> Now        white space is

             relevant
</pre>
```